a11eN756e64657261747461636b
Note: if it isn't obvious, none of the below or any of the decrypted message are intended to be real.
C:\TopSecret\vacant\alien_transmission.jpg:

C:\TopSecret\vacant\alien_transmission.bin:
0010000001
1101100010
0000001000
0000100000
0010000000
1000000010
0000001000
0001110110
0000101000
0010100010
1000001011
1100101001
0101110000
1000000010
1111001000
0000100011
0010000000
1000000010
0000001011
1100100000
0101110000
0010100010
0000001000
0000100000
0010000000
1010000010
1111001010
0100101111
0000101000
1000000010
1101001011
0100101101
0010000001
0111000010
0000001111
0000101101
0010110101
1111000010
0000001000
0000101111
0000101001
1100000110
1100011001
0101100001
0111001101
1001010000
1010001000
0000100000
0010000000
1000000010
0000001000
0000100000
0010000000
1000000010
0000001000
0001011110

C:\TopSecret\vacant\log.txt
...

In the year ####, scientists have discov######sing
high-fidelity cameras images sent from Alp########uri. 
The images were captured and encrypt#####ing very
prec#####aser movements. Although the source is unkno#####t
is apparent that spies have been o######h to surveil our
la#####e and com###########ms, including the A#########e,
apparent in their com###ication. Although humans are not
###able of #e##### the a###ns, this is the first ever
int####tion from ou######ace tha#####th has rec##ved, 
marking a significant milestone of human history. 

...

C:\TopSecret\vacant\hint_from_outer_space.wav transcription:
Utilize a device that emits light through
a process of optical amplification based
on the stimulated emission of electromagnetic 
radiation, an anacronym that originated as
an acronym for light amplification by stimulated
emission of radiation. Use half-transparent
reflection devices. Decrypt the puzzles by
shining light upon them. Trace your path to
the solution. The other file will fall similarly. 

C:\TopSecret\vacant\important.txt
- dont get too pixelated
- title hexadecimal
- asciis only in the first step
- trace the paths just like the image


What is the question? :)

@bobble, enigmatic-puzzle means that you have to decide how the puzzle has to be solved. Right now, it is not possible to check if the answer you got is the right one, or maybe only a partial answer.

@Lezzup usually the point is the answer is very obvious when it has been reached, could be a congratulations message or something along those lines

@Lezzup (with apologies for piling on) With this sort of puzzle, it's generally very clear when you've actually solved it. Obviously it's hard to know beforehand whether any given puzzle will turn out to have a nice satisfying solution, but I'd bet on this one having one. If it turns out it doesn't, that will be the time for downvotes, closing, etc.

In case anyone gets stuck, the solved puzzle should be three messages, contributing to a particular scenario. The solver is expected to deduce what the scenario is.

Added hint. ...

I will be bountying this question soon...

FAL is not relevant. (The lines that compose it might be.) The ovanel must be combined with the vzntr for it to make any sense (except for the word cyrnfr).

@Fluorine forgot to @ you...

@Fluorine consider posting a partial solution?

The title is not decrypted with onfrfvksbhe, but rather with what you call "havpbqr". Note that I have redacted havpbqr from the filename for a reason.

You're totally right, onfrfvksbhe was my first attempt, I forgot it turned out gibberish, and havpbqr gave the correct one afterwards

are you sure about rot13(gur bevragngvba bs gur svefg fynfu va gur guveq yvar bs gur ovanel qrpelcgrq... Gur bgure bevragngvba jbhyq tvir n avpr u... naq gur erfg jvyy fcryy bhg n pel sbe uryc)

sorry about it. help was intended, but somehow the rotation had happened during transcription.

It's strange that C: D: is Windows notation for disk volumes yet /(unix) is used instead of \\(windows) to mark paths. I doubt the path would be valid on any real-life operating system

I'll take your suggestion.

@Fluorine its up to you

Ah sorry @Fluorine, I deleted it :)

The scenario is:

 "Aliens" are "under attack", so they send a transmission to earth saying "Hi earth" and in a separate message they ask us for help, very politely, "Help please"

Break down of the clues:
First part (incorrect in el cato's answer)

 of the message is given by the title : a11eN756e64657261747461636b. The a11eN can be read as "alien" in leet speak, and the second part 756e64657261747461636b is hexadecimal (or bytes) code for unicode characters. When decoded it gives "underattack", so we get that aliens are under attack.

Second part

 is the picture. It represents a laser maze but like @el cato explained, the top right maze is a tutorial to learn how the puzzle works.


 


 In 1 we see that orange walls absorb the laser. In 2 we learn that black walls act like mirrors and in 3 we have that grey walls behave somewhat like one-way mirrors, letting the laser pass through in his original direction like glass and reflecting it with the angle of incidence like a mirror. The blue laser lets us confirm our inferred rules, as we reach all the blue > from the starting blue ->. Now we need to apply this to the rest of the picture


 


 Doing so spells out "Hi earth", the second part of the message

Third part (incorrect in el cato's answer)

 is the binary file. Interpreting it as Unicode binary, representing characters. We see it is once again a laser maze. And we get the following (with one small transmission error, probably a bit flip) by choosing the right behavior for each element:


 


 Which spells out "help please", completing the three part message.


Wow! I didn't think that the ^ was a laser instead of  of my 'presumed alignment marks'. Never thought it was that straight-forward!

This answer is wrong, but I still kept my answer as a reference. See @Fluorine's answer for the correct solution.

 attack

Here's my write-up:
Step 1:

 The top-right part of first picture portrays multiple laser path. If we follow the arrows in red we can infer a rule for laser reflection. 
 If we encounter a black bevel, we reflect the laser. 
 If we encounter a gray one, we reflect the laser (notice the arrow is slightly larger), and duplicate a passthrough one. 
 If we encounter a orange wall, we stop. 
 And if we follow the above rules and start from the bottom arrow in blue, we would verify that our rule stands. 
 Now, we just need to solve for the other parts of the message:
 

Through this process, the answer of the first part is:

 Hi earth

Part 2:

 This part is encoded in ASCII in binary.
 After conversion you'll have this: 



  v       v

 

(/)\ / #   / \ 

    (/)/

 --- \ <--|  /

please 

           ^



 We see a similar scenario, just like in the first picture. Each line contains 8 slots for either grey (in /, since we can see in the bottom line that the laser goes through), black (in (/), inferred), laser start (|), validation point (#, this is also inferred), or empty. 
 Applying the above rules again, and mark the slots the laser goes through as 1, otherwise 0. We then come to the following bits array: 

 00001000 
 00011111 
 11111100 

 Notice that the ^ serves as alignment marks, so the laser in the last line shoots at the 6th slot. 

 We concatenate the bit array from first till last line, and got: 
 000010000001111111111100

 Finally, we mask the the title without a11eN part with the bit array, 756e64657261747461636b & 000010000001111111111100, it gave us 61747461636b. 
 Breaking down into twos, that is 61 74 74 61 63 6b. Convert them from hexadecimal and ASCII, we get attack.


Wow, welcome to PSE, you got a big part of it I think. However, why didn't you rot13(qenj gur oyhr ynfre va gur cvpgher? Nyfb lbh ner zvffvat bar bgure pyhr gb svther bhg gur fpranevb, frnepu sbe zber rapelcgrq fghss...) (This part of the message is spoilered, if you want to see it you have to use a rot13 decypher)

Nice answer! I completely didn't expect the similarity (within .005 degrees)! Your decoding is correct, but I did not intend for the lasers to mark characters, only lines... (so no binary, the .bin just indicated ascii) plus the 16 is a bit arbitrary (one would expect 64, reading the same way as the other two numbers).

@Fluorine Thanks for the welcome. rot13(Naq gunaxf sbe gur fhttrfgvba. V'yy hcqngr zl svther va n zvahgr be gjb. Sbe 'bar bgure pyhr', vf vg va gur ynfg gjb cnegf? V ybbxrq guebhtu gur dhrfgvba uvfgbel naq gubhtug gurer jrer whfg uvagf. Vs abg, V nz cebonoyl zvffvat fbzrguvat urer. )

@elcato The final one is the title.

Exactly repeat what you did in the image to the decoded text of the binary file.

@sunny-lu Thanks for the hint. I guess rot13(nggnpx) is the answer?

@elcato for the title? nggnpx is not complete.

Since the puzzle has been solved, I'd like to share the original text of log.txt:

  In the year ####, scientists have discovered using high-fidelity cameras images sent from Alpha Centuri.  The images were captured and encrypted using very precise laser movements. Although the source is unknown, it is apparent that spies have been on Earth to surveil our language and computer mechanisms, including the ASCII table, apparent in their communication. Although humans are not capable of helping the aliens, this is the first ever interaction from outer space that Earth has recieved,  marking a significant milestone of human history.  !

Of course, you can put the year as whatever you like. :)
